# How could i get a Testname / Test status in JUnit

Tags: junit

I am new to JUnit . I am working on the ways to get a output like

classname / function name / status / description.

I figured that there is no other way to get success test name other than FrameworkMethod using Rule. Is it possible to set a Rule to a suite which s running with the help of JUnitCore/textui.Thx in advance.!!

Edit:- I tried testwatchman with Junit 4.9b2 but executing suites is not working for me. Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
@RunWith(Suite.class) 
@SuiteClasses({testclass1.class, testclass2.class}) 
public class junitCheck {
     private static String watchedLog;

     @Rule
     public MethodRule watchman= new TestWatchman() {
             @Override
             public void failed(Throwable e, FrameworkMethod method) {
                     watchedLog+= method.getName() + " " + e.getClass().getSimpleName()
                                     + "\n";
             }

             @Override
             public void succeeded(FrameworkMethod method) {
                     watchedLog+= method.getName() + " " + "success!\n";
             }
     };

}
```

---

```
public class testclass1 {

    @Test
    public void add()
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(4,2+3);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class testclass2 {


    @Test
    public void add1()
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(4,2+2);
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the TestWatchman rule.

Comment: what if i want to set a suitelevel Rule.. Thats not yet implemented ryt?

Comment: It looks as though class/suite-level rules are coming in JUnit 4.9: http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/07/24/rules-in-junit-4-9-beta-3/

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with the suite. So the only way is to add an org.junit.rules.TestWatcher to a common super class of the tests.